# Homebrew: Is it possible to see the effects of an install before proceeding?

Tags: homebrew, package-managers

I recently started using the Homebrew package manager, as a few project dependencies needed it for installation. Today, I decided to use it to install groovy. About halfway through the process, I started to worry about space. The install required many more dependency installations than I had expected.

I also noticed that I didn't get a prompt before Homebrew started to do it's thing. Usually, in a package manager, after using the install command, a prompt is displayed showing the changes that will result from installation. Then it usually says something along the lines of "Proceed? Y/n."

However this wasn't the case here. Homebrew just started downloading and installing.

**Is there a way to change the default behavior so the effects are displayed beforehand? If so, what is the required process.**